# Polymer 1.x: Formatting <paper-menu-button>

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

#### I have paper-button element ...

[This JSFiddle shows the target result I seek for the button hover effect](http://jsfiddle.net/L3bqphwe/2/). (i.e., the entire button fills the entire height of the toolbar and, without margin, needs to highlight when hovered).

#### ...but I need paper-menu-button element.

The above was using a `<paper-button>`. But I really want to use a `<paper-menu-button>`. [This JSFiddle is the best attempt I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/L3bqphwe/3/). (Notice how there is white space — that doesn't highlight on hover — both above and below the button.)

---

## Question

> **Please help me format the second JSFiddle to look (on hover) like the first JSFiddle.** (I.e., no white space. Fills entire height of toolbar.)
>
> Please provide a working JSFiddle or JSBin in your answer.

**Note:** I used the `x` character preceding many of the CSS style attributes as a quick way to comment out attributes I tried already but didn't work.

---

### Code

... this effect is the target ... http://jsfiddle.net/L3bqphwe/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Polymer Bin</title>
  <base href="http://element-party.xyz/">
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="all-elements.html">
  <style>
    paper-toolbar *:last-child {
        margin-right: -8px;
    }  
  </style>
</head>
<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
  <paper-header-panel>
    <paper-toolbar>
      <span>Header</span>
      <span class="flex"></span>
      <x-element></x-element>
    </paper-toolbar>
    <div>Content goes here...</div>
  </paper-header-panel>   
<dom-module id="x-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        --paper-button: {
          @apply(--layout-vertical);
          @apply(--layout-center-center);
        };
        --paper-menu-button: {
          @apply(--layout-vertical);
          @apply(--layout-center-center);
          height: 100%;
        };
        border-left: 1px solid white;
        height: 100%;
      }
      paper-menu-button {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        xborder-left: 1px solid var(--paper-grey-600);
        --paper-menu-button: {
          @apply(--layout-vertical);
          @apply(--layout-center-center);
          @xapply(--height-100%);
          xheight: 100%;
        };        
      }
      paper-button:hover {
        background: white;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      paper-button {
        --paper-button: {
          @apply(--layout-vertical);
          @apply(--layout-center-center);
        };
        color: white;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 0;
        margin:0;
        -o-transition      : .25s;
        -ms-transition     : .25s;
        -moz-transition    : .25s;
        -webkit-transition : .25s;
        transition         : .25s;
      }
    </style>
  <paper-button>Button</paper-button>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function(){
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-element'
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```

... what I have so far ... needs help ... http://jsfiddle.net/L3bqphwe/3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Polymer Bin</title>
  <base href="http://element-party.xyz/">
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="all-elements.html">
  <style>
    paper-toolbar *:last-child {
        margin-right: -5px;
    }  
  </style>
</head>
<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
  <paper-header-panel>
    <paper-toolbar>
      <span>Header</span>
      <span class="flex"></span>
      <x-element></x-element>
    </paper-toolbar>
    <div>Content goes here...</div>
  </paper-header-panel>   
<dom-module id="x-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        --paper-button: {
          @apply(--layout-vertical);
          @apply(--layout-center-center);
        };
        --paper-menu-button: {
          @apply(--layout-vertical);
          @apply(--layout-center-center);
          height: 100%;
        };
        border-left: 1px solid white;
        height: 100%;
      }
      paper-menu-button {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        xborder-left: 1px solid var(--paper-grey-600);
        --paper-menu-button: {
          @apply(--layout-vertical);
          @apply(--layout-center-center);
          @xapply(--height-100%);
          xheight: 100%;
        };        
      }
      paper-button:hover {
        background: white;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      paper-button {
        --paper-button: {
          @apply(--layout-vertical);
          @apply(--layout-center-center);
        };
        color: white;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 0;
        margin:0;
        -o-transition      : .25s;
        -ms-transition     : .25s;
        -moz-transition    : .25s;
        -webkit-transition : .25s;
        transition         : .25s;
      }
    </style>
    <paper-menu-button>
      <paper-button class="dropdown-trigger">Button</paper-button>
      <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item>Share</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
      </paper-menu>
    </paper-menu-button>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function(){
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-element'
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you give

```
height: 100%
```

to paper-button.x-element

but the parent is limiting this height.

So simply add

```
#trigger {
  height: 100%;
}
```

`#trigger` or `.style-scope.paper-menu-button`

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted. But on my end, your JSfiddle isn't rendering. Please help get it to render so I can see it and accept. Hm... that's weird. I just copied the code to a JSbin and it renders. But the white space problem isn't solved. http://jsbin.com/ficaquleki/edit?html,output

Comment: Dont know what happend. But my changes are not in the Code. Just add my code from my answer in your style at the top of your code and it will work :)

Comment: Oh. I see. You have to press the "update" button in JSFiddle to save the changes. (Which anyone can do... i.e., it's not "locked" or anything.)

Comment: Nice ! :) It is working? Dont forget to mark the question as solved so other people can see it.

Comment: No. Not working yet. I tried it a couple different ways already. Can you please just edit the code the way you describe because there are a few different ways I can interpret your response without seeing the code. Remember, just press the ***Update*** button and it will save your new version as `/4/` or something. BTW. I ***never*** forget to ***upvote and accept*** all answers to my questions (just look at my history, and you'll see) because I love to give rep to helpful people! Lol.

Answer (score 0):

Working code from accepted answer ...  jsbin.com/bisanocehu/1/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Polymer Bin</title>
  <base href="http://element-party.xyz/">
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="all-elements.html">
  <style>
    paper-toolbar *:last-child {
        margin-right: -5px;
    }
    #trigger {
       height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
  <paper-header-panel>
    <paper-toolbar>
      <span>Header</span>
      <span class="flex"></span>
      <x-element></x-element>
    </paper-toolbar>
    <div>Content goes here...</div>
  </paper-header-panel>   
<dom-module id="x-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        --paper-button: {
          @apply(--layout-vertical);
          @apply(--layout-center-center);
        };
        --paper-menu-button: {
          @apply(--layout-vertical);
          @apply(--layout-center-center);
          height: 100%;
        };
        border-left: 1px solid white;
        height: 100%;
      }
      paper-menu-button {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        xborder-left: 1px solid var(--paper-grey-600);
        --paper-menu-button: {
          @apply(--layout-vertical);
          @apply(--layout-center-center);
          @xapply(--height-100%);
          xheight: 100%;
        };        
      }
      paper-button:hover {
        background: white;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      paper-button {
        --paper-button: {
          @apply(--layout-vertical);
          @apply(--layout-center-center);
        };
        color: white;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 0;
        margin:0;
        -o-transition      : .25s;
        -ms-transition     : .25s;
        -moz-transition    : .25s;
        -webkit-transition : .25s;
        transition         : .25s;
      }
    </style>
    <paper-menu-button>
      <paper-button class="dropdown-trigger">Button</paper-button>
      <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item>Share</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
      </paper-menu>
    </paper-menu-button>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function(){
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-element'
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```